# C# - "Syntax error in update statement" when trying to update the access database using datagridview (also using OleDbCommandBuilder)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am displaying a data in datagridview and I am trying to update the database from datagridview. So I am using OleDbCommandBuilder to generate the update command. I get "Syntax error in update statement" when clicking on update button.

Here is my code:

```
 private void listBox9_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
        connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Trip Sheet Management System\\WABCO.mdb");
        sql = "SELECT ID,[TRIP COST] FROM TMSDETAILS";
        dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        connection.Open();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
        connection.Close();
  }


 private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        try
        {
            dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I click on update button, I get error in MessageBox saying "Syntax error in update statement"

Field 1: ID - Autonumber, primary key
Field 2: TRIP COST - Number

Comment: What is the command exactly when you debug your code? I don't see any update statement on your code.

Comment: There is no update statement.
Thats why I am using CommandBuilder

Comment: Maybe because you have closed the connection of your dataAdapter ?

Comment: No. I didn't close the connection of the dataAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys I found the answer by myself.

The error occurred because the field name contains a space i.e TRIP COST.

just add the two line next to command builder statement.

commandBuilder.QuotePrefix = "[";

commandBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]";

Here is the edited code.

```
 private void listBox9_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
    connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Trip Sheet Management System\\WABCO.mdb");
    sql = "SELECT ID,[TRIP COST] FROM TMSDETAILS";
    dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    dataTable = new DataTable();
    bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    connection.Open();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
    connection.Close();
}


private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    commandBuilder.QuotePrefix = "["; 
    commandBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]";

    try
    {
        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps others. :)

Comment: Really Helped to fix something, almost a couple years later..!! +1